# By frequency of actual usage, what percentage of the Korean language is 한자어?

Tags: word-origin, sino-korean-words

[The Wikipedia article on Sino-Korean vocabulary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Korean_vocabulary) states:

> Sino-Korean words today make up about 60% of the Korean vocabulary,
>   **though in actual speech (especially informally) native words are more
>   common.**

Are there any statistics on the percentages of 한자어 that are used in actual speech and writing? I am aware that the percentage would be very different between an academic paper and a chat between teenagers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most sources report the percentage of vocabulary in dictionaries, and the figures range from [53% to 70%](http://www.mt.co.kr/view/mtview.php?type=1&no=2013100810222055413&outlink=1) - this will really depend on the dictionary used to calculate the figure.

The running words frequency is the percentage of words actually found in a text.  This depends on the text used, but if a balanced representative corpus is used, you should get a fairly good estimate.

In 2002, the [National Institute of Korean Language (국립국어원)](http://korean.go.kr/#) published a study called [현대 국어 사용 빈도 조사](http://korean.go.kr/front/reportData/reportDataView.do?report_seq=303&mn_id=45) based on a corpus of 1,531,966 words, with the frequency of every word contained in the corpus.  Based on that study, a [newspaper article](http://www.mt.co.kr/view/mtview.php?type=1&no=2013100810222055413&outlink=1) reports that the percentage of word origins among running words are as follows:

- Native Korean words ("토박이말"): 54%
- Hanja words (한자어): 35%
- Foreign words (외래어): 2%

I couldn't confirm those figures myself, as they don't seem to be in the original article published by the 국립국어원, but rather calculated from the tables provided in the article.

Comment: The percentage doesn't seem to add up. 101% can be explained by rounding errors, but these only add up to 91%, perhaps one of them was mistyped to be 10% less then the actual value?